# Характеристики VPS сервера

Tags: xen, hosting, vps

Добрый день,Интересует вопрос по VPS хостингу. У меня есть хостинг Характеристики CPU и памяти выводит такие:

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU 2.67GHz

Mem: 1024

Может ли хостер "подкручивать" характеристики или это реальные?Я не совсем понимаю всю эту штуку с виртуализацией, просто пытаюсь найти аналогичного другого хостера за эти же деньги пока не нахожу. Вот и думаю может цифры не реальные?

### UPD

Есть два хостера. 2 тарифных плана

у одного 1024 мб RAM

Другой 512 мб.

У первого индекс UNIXBENCH 1782.7

у второго 486

Имеет смысл взять тот где меньше памяти но лучше результат теста?

Comment: Если столько оперативки устраивает - естественно да.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужны тесты производительности.

"Крутить" можно что угодно, но если тесты показывают - значит так и есть.

Comment: Достаточно UNIXBENCH? Или еще что-то?

Comment: нужны те тесты, что нужны, а не все подряд. Понятно, что хостер может пытаться экономить (от этого и зависит невысокая цена услуги), но это должно быть не в ущерб именно Вам! И что по каким-то тестам будет проседание по сравнению с реальной машиной - совершенно нормально, как и то, что оптимизация настроек гостевого окружения может повышать некоторые показатели.Так что проверяйте, что используете, а если есть недоверие хост-провайдеру лучше связаться непосредственно с ним напрямую (это их работа) и попросить объяснить то, что вас смущает в работе машин понятным языком.